# Unsupported command argument type: Resque::Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

Im attempting to run resque for a **rails 7** app on my machine like this: `QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work`

It fails with this:

```
rake aborted!
TypeError: Unsupported command argument type: Resque::Worker
Original Exception (TypeError): Unsupported command argument type: Resque::Worker

Original Exception (Resque::PruneDeadWorkerDirtyExit): Worker Davids-Mac-mini:38378:* did not gracefully exit while processing <Unknown Job>
```

I am sure `redis-server` is running correctly

This is my setup

**application.rb**

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :resque
```

**config/initializers/resque.rb**

```
require 'resque/server'

if Rails.env.development?
  Resque.redis = Redis.new(host: 'localhost', port: '6379')
else
  uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDIS_URL'])
  REDIS = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
  Resque.redis = REDIS
end
```

**application_job.rb**

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # Automatically retry jobs that encountered a deadlock
  # retry_on ActiveRecord::Deadlocked

  # Most jobs are safe to ignore if the underlying records are no longer available
  # discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError
end
```

**schedules_job.rb**

```
class SchedulesJob < ApplicationJob 
  queue_as :default

  def perform(id)
    puts 'Hello world!'
  end
end
```

**Rakefile**

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require_relative 'config/application'
require 'resque'
require 'resque/tasks'

task 'resque:setup' => :environment

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Comment: I have the same problem, when I pin my redis gem back to 4.8 it resolves the error. It seems to be something caused by redis-rb 5.0

Comment: Do you have redis configured to be persistent?  We have the same problem and think maybe some format changed but because redis usually runs in memory they did not need a data migration path.  I won't be ready to write an answer until we try it, which won't be for a while, but something you could check is deleting all the resque data in redis before running the new versions of the gems.